# Make Node.js speech recognition implementation work in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, speech-recognition

I'm making speech recognition in javascript. I found this algorithm called MFCC that I should use. I found Node.js implementation of that algorithm called [node-mfcc](https://github.com/vail-systems/node-mfcc).

Is there any way I can make it work in browser?

**EDIT:** Actually, I'm looking for speech comparison, not recognition. The result should be the percentage of similarity between 2 spoken phrases.

Comment: Check `browserify` or `webpack` projects

Comment: Have you done any research on this?

Comment: before implementing it check `web speech api` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API)

Comment: @vittore - only works (with some limitations too) for chrome

Comment: @JaromandaX chrome and ff 44

Comment: @vittore Isn't it behind a flag? I would argue that doesn't count. http://caniuse.com/#search=speech

Comment: OP: please edit the question with the comment you added to my answer regarding speech _comparison._

Comment: speech recognition does not work in firefox at all - read the notes on MDN

Answer (score 1):

Is your intent to re-implement speech recognition from first principles for study? If so, check out [browserify](http://browserify.org/), but you'll need to refactor out the command-line component and the dependency on node-wav from within node-mfcc, just for a start...

Otherwise, speech recognition in the browser in JavaScript has *already been done*:

1. [Pocketsphinx.js](http://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js/)
2. Native [SpeechRecognition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) WSAPI (and the [browser support matrix](http://caniuse.com/#search=speech)). Currently it is only supported in Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you help. Actually, I said it wrong. Speech recognition isn't exactly what I'm looking for. It's speech comparison. The program should return the match percentage between two spoken phrases.

Comment: In that case, check out the first comment. It will require refactoring the node module to work within your context. The _much simpler_ solution, if it's possible in your context, is to send the file to a node server for processing.